# variable in javascript en semantic

Tags: javascript

I am working on a program in javascript for speech to text and text to speech. I try to capture the spoken text in a variable and process it in a database to find an answer. the value of my variable is always 0.
my question is how can i put the spoken text in a variable in js and edit it in PHP? is it possible? am I having trouble with semantic?
 Thank you in advance.
below the code, myVar is a variable that always gets o value

```
var myvar = '';
var name = "";
var lengthOfName = name.length;
var transcript = '';
window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition ||
  window.SpeechRecognition;
let finalTranscript = '';
let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();

//let p = document.createElement('p');
//const words = document.querySelector('.words');
//words.appendChild(p);

recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;
recognition.continuous = true;
var testvar = "ggggggg";
recognition.onresult = (event) => {

    let interimTranscript = '';
    for (let i = event.resultIndex, len = event.results.length; i < len; i++) {
      var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;

      //transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        myvar = transcript;
        //document.getElementById("text").value=myvar;
        finalTranscript += transcript;
        //p = document.createElement('p');
        //words.appendChild(p);
      } else {
        interimTranscript += transcript;
        myvar = transcript;
      }
    }

    document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = finalTranscript + '<i 
    style = "color:#000d1a;" > ' + interimTranscript +' < />';
    //document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML += "\r\n";
```

Comment: if you want to send data from the browser to the server (i.e. where PHP is running) then you need to make a HTTP request to the relevant URL on the server - either by putting the data into form elements and then causing the form to be submitted, or by making an AJAX request.

Comment: P.S. It's unclear how `myVar` is related to this since you don't actually appear to use it for anything.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will try